# use of "that" keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have few javascript that has used the keyword "that" extensively.
I see a lot of posts talking about the javascript keyword "this".

I wanted to understand the meaning of this key word in javascript context and it's visibility/scope.

Something like

```
that.someFunctionaName(someParameter)
```

What does it mean?

I understand the keyword "this" always points to the owner of the current object.

Comment: that is not a keyword, but a simple variable name

Comment: `that` is not a keyword, it's a simple variable. For `this`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Please use the search function before asking a question, next time.

Comment: The concept behind this is, to use "that" as function wide global variable when you use closures to access the scope of the object. It's not a good way to do this in object oriented programming but in Javascript it's a quick way to solve such problems.

Comment: A great explanation on mysterious this behavior based on context [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/this/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`that` is not a keyword in JavaScript. I suspect the code that you have is using something in the class to define an instance of itself. For example:

```
function myClass()
{
    var that = this;
}
```

By doing this, you can ensure you're referencing the object, and not another element. For example, consider the following sample:

```
function myClass()
{
    var that = this;
    $('.myele').click(function() {  

        // 'this' refers to the element that was clicked.
        // 'that' still refers to the myClass() object.
    });
}
```

Comment: Another fairly commonly used variable for this is `self`, following the same logic.

Comment: @BenM thanks for the info. Yes it somewhat makes sense, I will do some more reading to understand the aspects of using such reference. And you are right, I got the "that = this" in my js code base after you suggested it. It more clear to me now.

Comment: hi @BenM my `that` looks like this `var that = {};` is it the same as `var that = this;`

Comment: No. `that { };` assigns an empty object to `that`.